# PostgreSQL - long running SELECT on Big XML - Data in TOAST

Tags: postgresql

I am currently analyzing why the application installed on top of PostgreSQL we are using is sometimes soo slow. The logfiles are showing that queries to a specific table have extremely long execution times.

I further found out, that it is one column on the table, which contains XML documents (ranging from a few bytes to one entry with ~7MB XML data), which is the cause of the slow query.

There are 1100 Rows in the table and a

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

has the same query execution time of 5 Seconds as

```
SELECT [XML-column-only] FROM mytable
```

But in contrast, a

```
SELECT [id-only] FROM mytable
```

has a query execution time of only 0.2s!

I couldn't produce any noticeable differences depending on the settings (the usual ones, work_mem, shared_buffers,...), there is even almost no difference in comparison between our production server (PostgreSQL 9.3) and running it in a VM on PostgreSQL 9.4 on my workstation PC.

Disk monitoring shows almost no I/O activity for the query.

So the last thing I went to analyze was the Network I/O.

Of course, as mentioned before, it's a lot of data in these XML Column. Total size for the 1100 rows (XML column only) is 36 MB. Divided for the 5 seconds running time, this are a mere 7.2MB/s Network Transfer, which equal around 60MBit/s. Which is a little bit slow, as we all are on Gbit Ethernet, aren't we? :D Windows Taskmanger also show a utilization of 6% for the Networking during the runtime of the query, which is in concordance with the manual calculation from before.

Furthermore, the query execution time is almost linear to the amount of XML data in the table. For testing I deleted the top 10% rows with the largest amount of data on the XML column, and the execution time (now ~18 instead of 36MB to transfer) dropped to 2.5s instead of 5s.

So, to get to the point: What are my options on the database administration side (we cannot touch or change the application itself), to make the simple SELECT for this XML-Data noticeable faster? Is there any bottleneck I didn't take into account yet? Or is this the normal PostgreSQL behaviour?

EDIT: I use pgAdmin III. The Execution plan (explain (analyze, verbose) select * from  gdb_items) shows a much shorter total runtime, than the actual query and the statement duration entry in the log:

```
Seq Scan on sde.gdb_items  (cost=0.00..181.51 rows=1151 width=1399) (actual time=0.005..0.193 rows=1151 loops=1)
Output: objectid, uuid, type, name, physicalname, path, url, properties, defaults, datasetsubtype1, datasetsubtype2, datasetinfo1, datasetinfo2, definition, documentation, iteminfo, shape
Total runtime: 0.243 ms
```

Comment: Which tool do you use to retrieve and display that data?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)` for the `select *` query. [**Formatted text**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The runtime of less then a milliseconds indicates that either the transmission of the data is slow or your SQL client is slow in _displaying_ that much data.

Comment: Okay, lesson learned, use psql with \timing options instead of pgAdmin... It gives me 0.25s for the `SELECT *`. thank you